# "Là, c'est la fin des haricots!"

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Que peut bien être la **fin** des haricots ? Et pourquoi est-ce un endroit de tous les dangers ?

Comment: C'est ce qui arrive quand la nourriture vient à manquer, exactement comme dans l'expression « Les carottes sont qu'huit ».

Comment: Effectivement le sens de *les carottes sont cuites* et  *c'est la fin des haricots* est proche.
Mais l'origine des carottes cuites est beaucoup plus évidente que de la fin des haricots !
C'est parce que *avoir ses carottes cuites* (apparu en 1878) veut dire être mourant, pour  l'étymologie :  
http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/les_carottes_sont_cuites

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ma première recherche sur google me donne une explication plutôt convaincante [1](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/30/la-fin-des-haricots/) :

> Au siècle dernier, on distribuait dans les internats des haricots aux élèves, quand on ne savait plus quoi leur donner en guise de nourriture. En effet, le haricot était considéré comme un aliment de base, voire médiocre. Quand il n’y avait même plus de haricots à manger, c’était la fin de tout. C’est de là que provient l’expression "C’est la fin des haricots" que l’on emploie quand on veut signifier que "c’est la fin du monde", souvent de façon ironique.

La seconde [2](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/la-fin-des-haricots.php) nous donne:

> L'une d'elles viendrait d'avant l'apparition de la télévision, la lucarne qui a tué la convivialité et les discussions familiales, phénomène encore aggravé par l'arrivée d'Internet[1](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/30/la-fin-des-haricots/).
>   A cette époque, les jeux de société étaient une occupation plus que courante. En famille, les mises ne se faisaient pas avec de l'argent, mais avec des choses diverses dont des haricots secs. Et quand un joueur n'avait plus de haricots, c'était vraiment la fin de tout pour lui, puisqu'il était éjecté de la partie (et qu'il ne pouvait même pas se rabattre sur sa PS2 ou sur un épisode des Shadoks ou de Desperate Housewives, par exemple).

Nous pourrons donc nous accorder à dire que "la fin des haricots" signifie que tout est perdu, et que les conséquences vont être terribles par la suite.

La fin des haricots n'est cependant pas un lieu. L'utilisation de "là" dans l'expression que tu proposes signifie "là où nous nous trouvons" sous entendu "à cet instant précis".

Answer (score 7):

La *fin des haricots*, c'est la fin de tout, le moment où l'on se rend compte qu'il n'y a plus de solution possible, que la catastrophe est inévitable. L'expression garde encore aujourd'hui un léger aspect familier, même si elle a légèrement vieilli.

L'expression *la fin des haricots* semble dater à l'écrit d'environ 1930, si l'on en crois les plus anciennes occurrences trouvées par [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22fin%20des%20haricots%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1937&lr=lang_fr). [André Thérive](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Th%C3%A9rive) l'a utilisée comme titre d'un [roman](http://www.sudoc.abes.fr/DB=2.1/SET=1/TTL=1/CLK?IKT=1016&TRM=Andre%CC%81+The%CC%81rive.+La+Fin+des+haricots,+roman). En 1938, R. Bourget-Pailleron, dans la [*Revue des deux mondes*](http://www.revuedesdeuxmondes.fr/), éprouvait encore le besoin d'expliquer le sens de l'expression dans sa [critique dudit roman](http://www.revuedesdeuxmondes.fr/user/details.php?code=11462):

> Le titre, goguenard et symbolique : *la Fin des haricots*, se réclame d'une expression populaire dont le sens pourra paraître obscur à quelques-uns. La « fin des haricots », dans un langage familier, cela signifie la fin de tout, le nom de ce légume étant délégué pour représenter d'une façon générale l'ensemble des bienfaits, alimentaires ou non, de l'existence.

L'expression [se répand ensuite assez vite](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fin+des+haricots&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3). Il est possible qu'elle ait été popularisée par une phrase que [Paul Reynaud](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Reynaud) [aurait laissé échapper](http://books.google.com/books?id=4MNHAAAAIAAJ&q=%22fin+des+haricots%22+Reynaud&dq=%22fin+des+haricots%22+Reynaud&hl=en&ei=D8CpTq6mFciRswaAmOGmBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA) et qui aurait été célèbre en son temps, mais je ne suis pas familier de cet incident et je ne trouve pas de source fiable à ce sujet.

Quelle est l'origine précise de l'expression ? Plusieurs théories ont été avancées. La plus plausible est que les haricots (le mot désignant ici les légumes secs en tout genre) sont le dernier aliment que l'on conserve quand tout ce qui est meilleur a été épuisé. L'origine serait peut-être [nautique](http://maxeville.voxdany.com.over-blog.com/article-j-aime-pas-les-fayots-50079905.html) ou [militaire](http://www.galanet.eu/dossier/fichiers/Les%20expressions%20issues%20de%20notre%20potager.doc) ou [scolaire](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/30/la-fin-des-haricots/).

D'après le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fin), on disait autrefois aussi, peut-être même avant, *la fin des petits pois* ou *la fin des grenouilles*. ([Rien de cela dans le corpus de Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fin+des+haricots%2Cfin+des+petits+pois%2Cfin+des+grenouilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3).)

Answer (score 5):

Le sens de l'expression a déjà été donné par M'vy et Gilles.

Pour ce qui est de l'origine de l'expression je préfère celle donnée dans  *Le dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) :  *la fin des haricots*  « la fin de tout » viendrait de l'emploi de haricots secs (ou de fèves) comme enjeu fictif.   *Des haricots*    pour dire «rien du tout» est apparu en 1911.

Par ailleurs un google ngram montre un pic de l'expression au moment de la deuxième mondiale, ce qui semble logique vue le contexte historique de la France à cette époque. Un autre pic, plus élevé, apparait à la fin du XX siècle, mais là, comme toujours, on se trouve devant le simple fait que le corpus accessible sur internet est plus vaste à partir des vingt dernières années du XXe siècle. Donc difficile de dire si l'expression était plus utilisée en 1990 qu'en 1943.